# Further optimized detecting lanes

Tags: python, opencv

I wrote a program to detect lanes on the road so that I can train it later on to turn it into an autonomous car. The game has a weird map in some sense that contains roads in a wide range from narrow roads to wider roads. Performance of detecting lanes in the narrow is good but when it comes to wider roads, the more the car is away from one lane, the harder to detect that line. Here are the two pictures that make my point more clear:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExqyW.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOGLk.png)

```
import cv2
from preparation.preprocess import createScreen, preprocess_image



while(True):
    #PressKey(W)
    screen = createScreen(0, 60, 850, 530)
    preprocessed_screen = preprocess_image(screen,[[0,245], [0, 140], [440,130], [850,140], [850,245]])
    cv2.imshow('Console',preprocessed_screen)
    if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break



import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import ImageGrab



# Given vertices and the image whose reason of interest is taken, returns an image whose pixels are black but the reason of interest.
# param | image : The image whose reason of interest is taken
# param | vertices : The boundraies that designate the reason of interest
# return |imagesize_roi : The image of reason of interest
def getReasonInterest(image, vertices):
    mask = np.zeros_like(image) # Creates a matrice with 0s of size image. (If the dimension is larger than 32, use zeros_like instead of zeros
    cv2.fillPoly(mask, vertices, 255) # Code every pixel as 255(11111111) in the area designated by vertices
    imagesize_roi = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask) # Since the area that is out of reason of interest consists of 0s, those pixels
    # arent going to change. Since the rest of the pixels are 1, simply what image contains is assigned to imagesize_roi.
    # Remember! 0 is black, 255 is white.
    return imagesize_roi



# Given coordinates on the diagonal, create a screen to be captures into python.
# param | top_left_x : X value of top left diagonal
# param | top_left_y : Y value of top left diagonal
# param | bottom_right_x : X value of bottom right diagonal
# param | bottom_right_y : Y value of bottom right diagonal
# return | RGB_img : The designated image of the given coordinates
# NOTE: Remember to scroll the real game screen where it belongs to.
def createScreen(top_left_x, top_left_y, bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y):
    printscreen_pil = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(top_left_x, top_left_y, bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y))
    printscreen_numpy = np.array(printscreen_pil).reshape((printscreen_pil.size[1], printscreen_pil.size[0], 3))
    RGB_img = cv2.cvtColor(printscreen_numpy, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) # Convert the colors what they really are
    return RGB_img



# Transform the given image into black and white image, then get the reason of interest that is designated by vertices and returns it.
# param | original_image : The image that the operations mentioned above are applied
# param | vertices : The boundraies that designate the reason of interest
# return | roi_image : The image that the operations mentioned above are applied
def preprocess_image(original_image, vertices):
    gray_image = cv2.cvtColor(original_image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) # color image : [255,255,255], gray image : [255] - MORE EFFICIENT
    processed_image = cv2.Canny(gray_image,300,400)
    vertices = np.array(vertices, np.int32)
    blurred_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(processed_image, (5,5), 0) # (5,5) probably the kernel filter size. Idk what the 0 is
    roi_image = getReasonInterest(blurred_image, [vertices])
    # second and third parameters are accuracies. fourth parameter is threshold : # of votes that needs to be considered as a line
    # five parameter is minimum length of a line. sixth parameter is the gap between two lines that can be considered as two different lines
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(roi_image, rho=6, theta=np.pi / 60, threshold=160, lines=np.array([]), minLineLength=40, maxLineGap=25) # returns two elements : lines as pixel, lines as radians.return roi_image
    line_image = findLanes(original_image, lines)
    if line_image == None:
        return original_image
    original_image_with_lanes = drawLanes(original_image,[[[line_image[0], line_image[1], line_image[2], line_image[3]],[line_image[4], line_image[5], line_image[6], line_image[7]],]],thickness=5)
    return original_image_with_lanes



# Draw the given lanes onto the given image so that the lanes can be followed.
# param | img : The image that lanes are drawn
# param | lines : Lanes that are drawn onto the given image
# param | color : Color of the lanes
# param | thickness : Thickness of the lanes
def drawLanes(img, lines, color=[0, 0, 255], thickness=3):
    if lines is None: # If there are no lines to draw, exit.
        return
    img = np.copy(img)
    line_img = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1], 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for line in lines:
        for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
            cv2.line(line_img, (x1, y1), (x2, y2), color, thickness)
    img = cv2.addWeighted(img, 0.8, line_img, 1.0, 0.0)
    return img



# Collects all edges on the screen, creates two lanes that can be followed.
# param | image : image the lanes that are drawn onto
# param | lines : edges that are detected on roi_image
# return | coordinates of the lanes if no exception is thrown, None otherwise
def findLanes(image, lines):
    left_line_x = []
    left_line_y = []
    right_line_x = []
    right_line_y = []
    try:
        for line in lines:
            for x1, y1, x2, y2 in line:
                if (y2 - y1 == 0) or (x2 - x1 == 0): # preventing from divided by zero excpetion and from slope == 0 etc
                    continue
                slope = (y2 - y1) / (x2 - x1)
                if np.math.fabs(slope) < 0.5: # eliminating horizontal lines
                    continue
                if slope <= 0:
                    left_line_x.extend([x1, x2])
                    left_line_y.extend([y1, y2])
                else:
                    right_line_x.extend([x1, x2])
                    right_line_y.extend([y1, y2])
        min_y = int(image.shape[0] * (2 / 5))
        max_y = int(image.shape[0])
        poly_left = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(left_line_y, left_line_x, deg=1))
        left_x_start = int(poly_left(max_y))
        left_x_end = int(poly_left(min_y))
        poly_right = np.poly1d(np.polyfit(right_line_y, right_line_x, deg=1))
        right_x_start = int(poly_right(max_y))
        right_x_end = int(poly_right(min_y))
        return [left_x_start, max_y, left_x_end, min_y,right_x_start, max_y, right_x_end, min_y]
    except:
        return None
```

How can I improvise this more? Thank you in advance.

Comment: "...the harder to detect that line..." Why is it harder? How are you doing it right now?

Comment: As seen in the second picture, although the yellow lane is on the left side, my red line can't detect it. Instead it draws the red line somewhere else.

Comment: Cool question, so you intend to find the left yellow line on the wider road instead of what it actually does now right? Have you tried changing the parameters of the `HoughLinesP`? Does it actually get the yellow line or not?

Comment: Thx for your reply @RickM. Well, I have a little bit of problem there, which is the fact that I couldn't understand some of the parameters of that function, I've read its documentation though. I've some doubts that the problem I'm referring to would be some issue with the parameter "threshold", but it may also be about rho or theta parameters as well. Since I couldn't understand the effect of them exactly, I didn't wanna trying randomly. Any idea where I can start off?

Comment: @H.Can as I said, you should first check if it *actually finds* the line. If it doesn't, you should definitely look at threshold. If it does, I'm pretty sure that your logic works, since in both the lines the _required lines_ have their start y values higher than the line which it finds correctly and it still works. I will also give it a try from my side and get back to you.

Comment: @RickM. I finally had the time to check what you told me.I played some of the parameters including threshold etc. but couldn't get any improvement yet...